# Easily optionally render sections

Tags: tags

My resume is written in LaTeX, and as new things come up, naturally old accomplishments and details become omitted. However, I would still like to keep them in the tex file, as of now they are commented out.

Ideally, I would like to be able to easily render two versions of the resume, the `current` version with only the most relevant details, and `full version`, one with everything. Is it possible to add a tag to each section to label as `old`, and easily switch between the two resumes by changing a single variable or flag, so that the `old` entries are optionally rendered?

Thank you.

Comment: `\newif\ifprintold`  then `\ifprintold   old stuff \fi`  around each section that is conditional

Comment: That is great, thank you!